# Implement a stepper with jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create something like this
[image]

The problem is how do i align the progress bar with respect to the cycle not the whole column that contains center and feature name

Code

```
private fun LazyListScope.progress(currentPage: SignupPage) {
    stickyHeader {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.White)
                .padding(vertical = 16.dp),

            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        ) {
            val pages = SignupPage.values()
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                pages.forEach { page ->
                    val isCompleted = page.isCompleted(currentPage)
                    val isCurrent = page == currentPage
                    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                        ColorCircle(
                            bgColor = if (isCompleted) JazaBlue else ChineseWhite,
                            size = 40.dp,
                            border = 1.dp,
                            borderColor = if (isCurrent) JazaBlue else Color.Black,
                        ) {
                            if (isCompleted) {
                                Icon(
                                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Check,
                                    contentDescription = null,
                                    tint = Color.White
                                )
                            } else {
                                Text(text = "${page.pos}")
                            }
                        }
                        Height(size = 4.dp)
                        Text(text = stringResource(id = page.shortTitle), fontSize = 12.sp)
                    }

                    if (page.pos < pages.last().pos) {
                        LinearProgressIndicator(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .weight(1f)
                                .height(8.dp),
                            progress = if (isCompleted) 1f else 0f,
                            color = if (isCompleted) JazaBlue else Color.LightGray,
                        )

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Result

[image]

How can i propely align the progress bar in between

Comment: Setting the size of the circles and then using part of that size `(circleHeight - barHeight) / 2` to set the paddings (top padding) of the bar to align it does not work in your case? If not, you could use the ConstraintLayout since this UI would probably not be a performance hit when using it.